# OS X page up, page down movement keys and cursor focus in finder

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, finder

When using the <kbd>page up</kbd> and <kbd>page down</kbd> keys in Finder, the cursor stays in the same spot, even though the window has moved elsewhere.

Is there a way to move the cursor, page by page in Finder?

Comment: I have deleted my answer because it no longer applies to your question. It was a good fit before when you were asking about `home` and `end`, but I've got nothing for you on `page up` and `page down`... sorry.

Comment: Why do you think the cursor needs to move when you're scrolling exactly?

Comment: He would like to do that somehow, he never said this should be default behaviour for everybody.

Comment: Seems there is still no solution after 11 years. For those who need at least `Home`/`End` with cursor, here are hotkeys: `⌥`+`▲`, `⌥`+`▼`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no way to accomplish that in OS X’s Finder and it’s very annoying that there’s no way to move the cursor too. The only solution would be to start typing the file name you want to go… but that’s lame.